# Uncaught TypeError: Object(…) is not a function in internal Vue3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I have strange error, i don’t know what causing this but last time i develop my project was fine. After no reason my chrome browser lost its cache data (next day). when i run my vue3 project the error appears. What console logs said

```
App.vue?3dfd:11 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at eval (App.vue?3dfd:11)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/index.js?!./src/App.vue?vue&type=template&id=7ba5bd90
```

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8p4d.png)

And that pointing to something right before

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgTmR.png)

This is my main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import Notifications from 'vue3-vt-notifications'
import { store } from './stores'
import Particles from 'particles.vue3'

// import tailwind css
import '../src/styles.css'

// firebase auth service
import { projectAuth } from './firebase/config'

let app
projectAuth.onAuthStateChanged(() => {
    if(!app){
        app = createApp(App)
        .use(router)
        .use(store)
        .use(Particles)
        .use(VueAxios, axios)
        .use(Notifications)
        .mount('#app')
    }
})
```

and this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "build-css": "tailwindcss build src/styles.css -o public/styles.css"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@dafcoe/vue-collapsible-panel": "^0.2.0",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.10.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "d3": "^7.0.0",
    "d3-svg-legend": "^2.25.6",
    "d3-v6-tip": "^1.0.9",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "firebase": "^8.2.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.1",
    "firebaseui": "^4.7.1",
    "js-md5": "^0.7.3",
    "jspdf": "^2.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "particles.vue3": "^1.12.2",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
    "vue-clipboard3": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-disqus": "^5.1.0",
    "vue-dropdowns": "^1.1.2",
    "vue-google-signin-button": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-instantsearch": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-load-image": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
    "vue-meta": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "vue-nav-tabs": "^0.5.7",
    "vue-rate": "^2.4.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vue-typewriter": "^2.2.1",
    "vue3-carousel": "^0.1.13",
    "vue3-datepicker": "^0.2.4",
    "vue3-vt-notifications": "^1.0.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

In Addition, I don’t know if this related or not every time in run serve. it finish at 98% with this warning:

[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm1Hb.png)

Somebody please help me

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, and finally found that when I imported nanoid, deconstruction was not used. After adding {}, the error was resolved. You can see if it is the problem of importing third-party libraries.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).